# Convert included .eps files to .pdf with xetex during the first compilation only

Tags: xetex, pdf, eps

Is there a way to have xetex convert `*.eps` files, included with `\includegraphics`, to `*.pdf` during the first compilation only and subsequently use the generated `*.pdf` files, as `pdflatex` does?